# How can i put label to my node in d3 directed graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a plnkr which creates node directed graph something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Usru9pGp98ju2d0St6Wz?p=preview

Currently it displays the node title when we hover over it using this function:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
        textTarget = d

        text.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')
            .text(d.id)
            .style('display', null)

        d3.select(this)
          .style('fill', colors.nodes.hover)

        d3.selectAll(childNodes(d))
            .style('fill', colors.nodes.hover)
            .style('stroke', colors.nodes.method)
            .style('stroke-width', 2)

        d3.selectAll(parentNodes(d))
            .style('fill', colors.nodes.dep)
            .style('stroke', colors.nodes.method)
            .style('stroke-width', 2)
    })
```

But my idea is to show the label everytime.

I found some similar question where they have asked to append label to node, so I tried this:

```
node.append("text")
.attr('transform', function())
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')
.text(d.id)
.style('display', null)
```

But doing this breaks my graph.

I am little new to d3 world, so not able to figure out what exactly is going wrong in this case.

Can any one help me to display label always for all the node (either inside the node circle or appended with it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach:**

So my approach to that would to to create group elements `g` with `circle` and `text` inside them, and then we can use force layout to position them with transform. This way we only care about group element position and circle with text should follow that position. So the node structure might look like that:

```
<g transform='translate(30,70)'>
    <circle r='3'>/<circle> 
    <text>sample text</text>
</g>
```

**Code:**

You have quite a lot of code in your sample so I'll just focus on having persistent labels over circles. This might break some other things I'm not focusing on but should give you direction and hopefully you'll be able to fix the rest if not fell free to ask.

Using your plunker first thing you have to do it so associate data with `g` elements instead of `circle` :

```
node = vis.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.filename })
    .enter().append('g');
```

Then you can append circles to those `g` elements, and in this case there is no need to define `cx` and `cy` as this is taken care of by `transform` applied to `g` elements, so all you need to specify is `r` and any other styles you wan to apply:

```
node.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr('r', function(d) {
    return scale * (d.root ? 8 : d.module && !d.native ? 5 : 3)
})
(...)
```

Now you can add your labels:

```
node.append('text')
.text(function(d){return d.id})
.style('text-anchor',middle); // this will center label horizontally
```

One last step is to update `on 'tick'` function as before it was updating circle position and now we want it to update `g` position, so instead of:

```
node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
```

you should do:

```
node.attr('transform', function(d) { 
      return 'translate('+ d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; 
    });
```

And here you have your plunker with my changes, hope thats what you asked for.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q69DkEH5Z9aOe92UwlOB?p=preview

Fell free to ask any more questions if you have any :)

Comment: Since you seem to be new at S.O. I upvoted your answer, which is correct. However, next time, just vote to close it as a duplicate: this **exact** same question has been asked/answered at least 1e6 times!

Comment: Hi, @GerardoFurtado my question is somewhat different.. question asked in previous question is mostly for v4.. my requirement is kind of different.

Comment: And as I mentioned in my question that I had tried adding the solution suggested in the previous question but it broke my chart.

Comment: @kaounKaoun Sorry to say, but your question has nothing different from the other ones, the requirement is exactly the same. And your solution is very wrong, using properties without the anonymous function, of course it will break the code!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado When u already  know  I am doing something wrong in my question, then that is what makes it different from the previous one..may be you could have helped me correcting my mistake . .. anyway Thanks

Comment: @Mateusz thanks a lot for helping me out.. being new to d3, I was unsure about your approach but the plunkr helped me a lot. Thanks a lot again.